# How to replace current url using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change url completely using following way.

```
let mycomplteUrl = 'http://localhost/tracks/id/4/39'; // http://localhost/tracks/id/4/39/4 or 
props.history.push(`${mycomplteUrl}`);
```

I'm dynamically creating this mycomplteUrl variable. sometimes variable can be something like

```
http://localhost/tracks/id/4/39 or http://localhost/tracks/id/4/39/4 or http://localhost/tracks/id/4/39/4/5 (dynamic) or any
```

it is the same only up to `http://localhost/tracks/id/4` this part. I need to replace whole url just like `window.location.href = mycomplteUrl` in normal javascript, but using props.history.push because i need to avoid from page refresh

Comment: can you share the before and after urls to understand. Basically, do the urls have a `#` for navigation ?

Comment: no , but it can have dynamic path like http://localhost/tracks/id/4/8383/82/134/3929/....
issue is I can not say how many ../ (for parent location) I should have

Comment: Have you tried `useHistory` ? Here is a reference : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory. This could solve your issue of navigation.

Comment: I'm calling this function in side a function. I'm getting an error saying '... which is neither a React functional component or a custom react hook functin'

Answer (score 7):

Note: for React Router v6

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyComponentOrHook() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // push
    navigate(someUrl );     // syntax
    navigate("/about");     // example

    // replace - OP's question
    navigate(someUrl , { replace: true });      // syntax
    navigate("/about", { replace: true });      // example

    return ... // JSX or hook return values
}
```

Also, avoid using `window.location` if you're using React Router, except in rare cases (example - to navigate to an external link).

Reason:

1. The whole point of using a library React Router is to ease client-side routing so we don't have to do `window.location...`.
2. `window.location` causes a reload, which should be avoided in React apps (or any SPA), mostly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid from a page refresh you can do it in this way

```
window.history.pushState({}, null, "/newPathname");
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually changes the Url. But however, it needs manual enter to go to the Url. I need to go to the URL also. What is the property to be changed for that

Answer (score 0):

props.history.replace(mycomplteUrl);

Comment: i tried it but still, it appends to the existing URL

Answer (score 0):

Try the below way and define the exact URL you want.

```
  window.location.replace(`http://localhost:3000/${dynamic_value}`);
```